# Bundler using old version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am using Bundler for my Rails application. When I list installed bundler gems it lists `1.4.0.pre.1` and `1.3.15` and running `bundler -v` yields `1.4.0.pre.1` (which is what i want).

However, when I try to run my application it says current bundler version is `1.0.15`. This version is not installed as a gem and I cannot figure out how to remove it (`gem uninstall bundler -v 1.0.15` wont work since this version is not installed as a gem).

I have tried updating and installing new versions, but nothing is working. Please help, I've been stuck for hours. Thank you.

Comment: How are you starting your rails app? Do you have multiple Ruby versions installed? Are you sure that Rails is using the correct one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running:

```
$ which -a bundle
```

This will tell you the location of all the instances of bundler found on your computer.

From there, you should be able to locate the offending version of bundler and uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working and giving results 'which bundle' is not! I ended up wiping rails and ruby from my system and reinstalling everything through rvm so it is better managed. Wish I had checked out the root of that old bundle version this way first!

Comment: this is maddening. which -a bundler says its v2.0 but bundler --version says 1.7.2

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when using vagrant

```
[vagrant@precise32:/vagrant (master)]$ sudo gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.11.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.11.2
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score -1):

try running this on you app console:

```
bundle update
```

Comment: that just updates the gems, it works, but when I try to start my rails server it reverts back to the old version

Comment: check your gemfile.lock file and check the bundler version there

Comment: in the Gemfile.lock it lists

bundler (= 1.4.0.pre.1)