# Using wrong bundler version when generating rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I am getting the next error after running the command `rails generate model Setting target:text`.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.0.15)
```

This means that it is listing a bundler version that doesn’t seem to be installed on my machine.

**Some details:**

Ubuntu 12.0.4

```
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.7.12
$ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
$ gem -v
2.4.5
$bundle exec rails -v
Rails 4.1.6
$ which ruby -a
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I have already tried:

- bundle exec before the command
- bundle install
- bundle update
- uninstalling libv8
- updating the bundler version
- `bundle _1.7.12_ install` and `bundle _1.7.12_`

And checked similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194091/bundler-using-old-version) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092928/how-to-bundle-install-when-your-gemfile-requires-an-older-version-of-bundler) without luck.

`bundle exec rails s` works, but without `bundle exec` it shows the same error.

Right now I am unable to use models on my application, does anyone know what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your Issue:

```
 In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.0.15)
```

Your rails 4.1.6 needs bundler having `version >= 1.3.0` But your current bundler version is `1.0.15.` 
Give a try removing your `Gemfile.lock` file

```
gem install bundler 
#let's say it installed 1.7.2 Version for you. 
bundle _1.7.12_ --version
bundle install
rails generate model setting target:string
```

Comment: I have tried but it is still returning the same error. The version of bundler is 1.7.12 but keeps saying it's 1.0.15.